# Grant the framework orchestrator access to itself for the 'Pipeline Already Running' utility

Tags: procfwk

How do I grant the framework orchestrator access to itself allowing the 'Pipeline Already Running' to occur?

In the documentation found here: https://mrpaulandrew.github.io/procfwk/pipelinealreadyrunning

It states:

> Data Factory must explicitly be granted access to itself in order to query its own pipeline runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is via the Azure portal control/management plane UI.

- **If** the framework pipelines are running from **Azure Data Factory**

In the Azure portal, navigate to the Access Control (IAM) panel for the Data Factory instance.

Add a new Role Assignment using the Service Principal name that matches the Data Factory instance (itself).

Grant permissions using the Microsoft predefined Owner role. Shown below.

[image]

- **If** the framework pipelines are running from **Azure Synapse Analytics**

The 'Pipeline Already Running' utility is not currently supported.